# Setting up write flags for Aerospike list operation using PHP

Tags: aerospike

I am trying to add unique elements to the lists. I found that there is write flag option ADD_UNIQUE but I failed to make it work using the PHP client. I can not find this option in the list of available options for the appendList method (for example). I am using client for php 7.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with PHP - but in Java, I recommend OR-ing 3 flags - ADD_UNIQUE, NO_FAIL and PARTIAL to successfully add unique items to a list.